# Split huge svg text path

Tags: svg, svg-path

I have very-very huge text path on svg. But this path it's one word, how I can split this word into individual letters? 
For example:

```
<svg>
   <g>
      <path id="Code.svg" class="cls-1 path" d="one letter path"
      <path id="Code.svg" class="cls-1 path" d="two letter path"        
      etc.
   </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 2):

All of the "letters" in your big path will consist of one or more sub-paths.
All sub-paths start with either an 'M' or an 'm' character.

So if you are editing the file by hand in a text editor, look for an "M" or an "m" and split the path there.   But like I said some letters will consist of more than one sub-path - for example any letter that has a hole (such as an "O").

So, for example

```
<path d="M... M... m... M ..."/>
```

might become

```
<path d="M..."/>
<path d="M... m..."/>
<path d="M..."/>
```